# Logout button don't appear after login in django

Tags: django-login

I am trying to make a Django login form, my problem is when the user logged in with his user name and password the login button(**inside my navbar**) is not changing into the logout button, but it should change to the logout button. Here logout features do not appear anytime. and this system always stays in the logged in the situation. How to enable the logout option to complete the login form?

in **views.py:**

```
@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account is not active")

        else:
            print("Some try to login and failed")
            print("Username: {} & password: {}".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse("Invilide login details supplied")

    else:
        return render(request, 'app27/login.html',{})




@login_required
def special(request):
    return HttpResponse("You are loged in")
```

in **HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Django</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'app27:register' %}">Register</a>
        </li>

                {% if user.is_authenticate %}
                <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'app27:logout' %}">Logout</a>
        </li>
                {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'app27:user_login' %}">Login</a>
        </li>
                {% endif %}

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

my **login form's HTML** is:

```
<form class="" action="{% url "app27:user_login" %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">

      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="" value="Login">

    </form>
```

the **urlpartterns** was:

```
path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
path('user_login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('basic_app/', include('app27.urls')),
path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
path('special/', views.special, name='special'),
```

please help me to complete this login and logout functions? and where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written `user.is_authenticate` instead of `user.is_authenticated` in your HTML file.
Incorrect:      `{% if user.is_authenticate %}`
It should be like This,
correct: `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`